# Python: functions in class's methods return None instead bool (aka sloppy pathfinding)

Tags: python, function, class, reference, path-finding

I'm trying to somehow rectify why I cannot get any satisfying results calling one method after another.
 
at start I have a 2-dim table [7x9] with cards that create a maze. 
for instance:

```
   , A.  , B.  , C.  , D.  , E.  , F.  , G.  ,      
   +-----+-----+-----+--#--+-----+-----+-----+
0. |     |     |     :#####:     |     |     |
   +-----+-----+-----+--#--+-----+-----+-----+
1. |     |     |     |  #  |     |     |     |
   +-----+-----+-----+--#--+-----+-----+-----+
2. |     |     |     |  #########:     |     |
   +-----+-----+-----+--#--+--#--+-----+-----+
3. |     |     |     |     |  #  |     |     |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+--#--+-----+-----+
4. |     |     |     |     |  #########:     |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+--#--+-----+-----+
5. |     |     |     |     |  #  |     |     |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+--#--+-----+-----+
6. |     |     |     :#################:     |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+--#--+--#--+-----+
7. |     |     |     |     |     |  #  |     |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--#--+-----+
8. |     |     |     |     |     :#####:     |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--#--+-----+
```

starting with point **D0** I want to check if the path made of cards reached point **F8**
I don't need shortest way or anything, just to know, that the path exists. 
I successfully coded a couple simple functions that are checking that within a class, but the main class method is not returning the True / False to the place where it was called from.
You can judge me by my way of coding, but I never wrote anything that big in Python ;P

Classes:
**Board**

```
class Board(object):
    board = []
    def __init__(self):
        for y in range(0,9):
            #...        
    def print_board(self):
        # implemented

    def getBoard(self):
        return self.board
```

**GameBoard**

*class short idea:*

```
class GameBoard(Board):

    def __init__(self, cardsInHand):

    def gameView(self):

    def checkPath(self):

        def right(poz, pa):
        def left(poz, pa):
        def down(poz, pa):
        def up(poz, pa):
        def doNext(poz, pa):

    def pushCard(self, pos, newCard , force = False):
```

and the important methods:

```
    def __init__(self, cardsInHand):
        Board.__init__(self)
        self.cards = cardsInHand

    def checkPath(self):
        poz = [0,3] # Starting position
        conns = [] # skip this
        tPath = [] # temporary path
        ret = False 
        test = 0
        def right(poz, pa):
            if len(self.board[0]) - 1 > poz[1]: # can be checked right
                if 1 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1]].entries: # has route to the right 
                    if 3 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1] + 1].entries: #the next has matching route
                        nl = [poz[0], poz[1] + 1]
                        if nl not in pa:
                            pa.append(nl)
                            doNext(nl , pa)
                        else :
                            pa = []
        def left(poz, pa):
            if  poz[1] > 0:
                if 3 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1]].entries:
                    if 1 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1] - 1].entries:
                        nl = [poz[0], poz[1] - 1]
                        if nl not in pa:
                            pa.append(nl)
                            doNext(nl, pa)
                        else:
                            pa = []
        def down(poz, pa):
            if len(self.board) - 1 > poz[0]:
                if 2 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1]].entries:
                    if 0 in self.board[poz[0] + 1][poz[1]].entries:
                        nl = [poz[0] +1, poz[1]]
                        if nl not in pa:
                            pa.append(nl)
                            doNext(nl , pa)
                        else :
                            pa = []
        def up(poz, pa):
            if  poz[0] > 0:
                if 2 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1]].entries:
                    if 0 in self.board[poz[0] - 1][poz[1]].entries:
                        nl = [poz[0] - 1, poz[1]]
                        if nl not in pa:
                            pa.append(nl)
                            doNext(nl , pa)
                        else :
                            pa = []
        def doNext(poz, pa):
            ways = []
            output = None
            if poz == [8, 5]: # the point '**F8**'

                ways.append(pa)
                output = True

            else:
                if 1 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1]].entries:
                    right(poz, pa)
                if 2 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1]].entries:
                    down(poz, pa)
                if 3 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1]].entries:
                    left(poz, pa)
                if 0 in self.board[poz[0]][poz[1]].entries:
                    up(poz, pa)
                output = False
            return output
        #print 'Expect False or True: ', str(doNext(poz, tPath))
        return str(doNext(poz, tPath))
```

As the last ***checkPath()*** print eventually should return (print) True at some point but it never does. 
further in this class I have method:

```
def pushCard(self, pos, newCard, force = False):
        ...
        ...
        win = False 
        ...
        # unimportant code
        ...
            if force == True:
                allow = True
            if allow == True:
                self.board[pY][pX] = newCard
                if self.checkPath():
                    print "The path exists"
                    win = True
            else:
                #cannot put card here
                win = False
        return wynik
```

Following, I cannot also get right result during gameplay:

```
for num in range(0, 12):
    input = str(raw_input( str(num + 1) + ". Card position and identity:  'An T' "))
    inPar = input.split(" ")
    if len(inPar) == 2:
        if gra.pushCard(inPar[0], Karta(inPar[1])):
            print ("end of the game")
            break
        else:
            print ("try again")
        gra.gameView()
        else:
            print("bad input")
```

The function doNext() never returns True, but during testing I got many times a feedback, that the path has been found. 
I'm using Python 2.6.6, not able to upgrade.

Any help would be appreciated.